# Is there any extension that can slow down the browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for an extension that can slow down the connection from my browser to my server. is there any extension or application can do that?

Comment: Developer Tools -> Network tab.

Comment: but I don't see any options to slow down the connection. I mean something that can make the transfer process slower so that I can test some of my server-side features.

Comment: It's there, the network type/speed selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to wOxxOm and tkausl.
Simply just go to Developer tools > Network > select the last option.
[image]